# namespace и агрументы функции

Tags: c++

Допустим у меня есть функтор и некий класс определенные в `namespace`

```
namespace A {
  class Alfa{};
  class Beta{
    void operator()(Alfa &a);
  };
}
```

Которые используются в `cpp` подобным образом:

```
using A::Beta;
void Beta::operator()(Alfa &a){};
```

Так вот: что говорит по этому поводу стандард? Нужно ли указывать для `Alfa` явно namespace или нет? Просто столкнулся с тем, что компиляторы `clang`, `mingw`, `gcc` отрабатывают верно на последней строке, а воt `msvc` выдает ошибку из-за того, что не указан `namespace` для класса `Alfa`.